# How to preview a links in Recyclerview

Tags: url, android-recyclerview

I need to preview links of pages in `recyclerview` . I used this Library : https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Android-Link-Preview  but it does not work. anyone know another way ?

Comment: Can you post your sample code or any error you receive.

Comment: No, it is not a error. Just because there is not exist a library to preview URL in a scroll list. The library I post in this post can preview the urls but only if the urls are not put in scroll list. The library uses asyncTask so the result will come a little late, that is why the library does not work, it will make wrong position in our list.

Answer (score 0):

Based on our chat in the comments section, you want to add the preview at some position in your scroll list. In that case, you can maintain some state (eg. position) in `LinkPreviewCallback`. So that when the preview results are ready, based on the maintained state, you can find the exact view where preview needs to be rendered.

Create a Class and Implement `LinkPreviewCallback`.

```
class MyPreviewCallback implements LinkPreviewCallback {
    int position;

    public MyPreviewCallback(int position) {
        super();
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPre() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPos(SourceContent sourceContent, boolean b) {
       // update adapter list item based on the position.
    }
}
```

Pass callback to the crawler.

```
textCrawler.makePreview(new MyPreviewCallback(3), url); // passing position
```

The main idea is basically to maintain some state in your class which will let you identify the exact `View` to be updated with Preview.